# Collect sensor data only for a specific period of time

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am trying to collect accelerometer data on android for a specific period of time. Thus far I managed to find solutions for collecting data every X seconds, however what I need looks like this:

Call a method -> collect data for X seconds -> Calculcate various things -> Return result.

At the moment my calculations are done in onSensorChanged (SensorEvent event). How could my desired behaviour be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to do this could be to set up a HandlerThread (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) which collects your Accelerometer data (removes your calculations from the main looper as well). Then you can post a runnable on it shutting it down after the desired period of time.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(mSensorEventsThread.getLooper());
mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorEventListener, mAccelerometerSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI, handler);
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable () {
    public void run () {
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mSensorEventListener);
        mSensorEventsThread.quitSafely();
    }
}, YourTimeOut);
```

Comment: I am fairly new to android programming and am not sure hot exactly to implement your solution. Could you recommend me some tutorial perhaps where I can gain a better understanding of how this works and how this should be implemented? Also where exactly would I insert the code you provided and how would I acces the accelerometer values, as I see no event.

Comment: You'd get your sensor events in mSensorEventListener, which would be an implementation of a SensorEventListener, working just as I assume your current code does.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Only got around to testing it this morning. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does my answer helped??